# Is it better to have SQL Server parse a large multi document XML or send it each document separately

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, vb.net

I need to request the XML from PubMed like

```
    https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=pubmed&id=27087788,28322247,26158412&retmode=xml
```

The example has 3 IDs but the request can be as much as 200 at a time. The request is being done by a .NET web service. I am looking for the most efficient way to process the XML files. I know that the the term "best" or "efficient" is very subjective and dependent upon many things but:

Is it better to send the entire string to the SQL Server database (if it is even possible because of length or possible nesting levels) and let it parse the document and save it to the database or is it better to parse the document in the web service using a `XMLTextReader` or XML Document Object and send each document? Each document needs to be saved as a separate record.

Thanks for your information.

Comment: use XML column Index for large data. this will cut the execution time by 3-4 times.

Comment: @MerHardik In most cases an XML index is not a good choice... You might [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43027179/5089204) and the link you find there...

Comment: Sounds good but how should I get the documents in?  One at a time from the web service, maybe 10 at a time and have MS SQL parse or possibly even XML bulk import?

Comment: Have you considered *measuring* it and seeing what works well? At the moment, only you know what your database structures are and how much processing you're performing on these documents.

Comment: Also depends on how you want to send each document. Multiple request or to a store procedure that accept an array of documents. Depends on which server has the most available resource, is the SQL database saturated with high amount of important request, or is the web site cpu always near 100%. The speed in your dev environment might be totally different than production.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was: Why SQL-Server? Why send all this data around? Do the parsing in C#!

But - on the second sight: If I understand this correctly, you want to read many different XML files and store them in your database.

Now I'd rather ask: When do you need to retrieve data from these XMLs and do you need to store extracted data in *relational* tables? Would it be a possible approach for you to store alle these XMLs *as-is* in XML typed columns and read them on demand?

You can pass your XML as C#-string (which is *unicode*) and insert this directly into an XML-typed column. To avoid any hassel you should cut away the first lines (`<xml>`declaration and `DOCTYPE`) and start with `<PubmedArticleSet>`.

The rest should be easily transfered and stored in SQL-Server.

If you need help on *how to read this?* Just come back with another more pointed question.

About your *Which is faster* question you [might read this](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Comment: I want to end up with 2 columns the ID in the string which is also in the XML file and the entire XML document.  So the url in my example is 3 records with 2 fields each.  In the past I have been parsing in the web service and opening and closing a connection for each document but I am in the process of rewriting my application and no better time to rethink the entire process.  I have a stored procedure that parses the XML as a nightly process and stores a ton of data in relational tables

Comment: @user1314159 As there is a SP already doing the reading part, you might just shuffle the XML *as-is* into a staging table (with or without accompaining data). Let your nightly SP read from this staging table, transfer whatever is needed and delete all handled XMLs from the staging table...

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I'll try send the server the entire XML string and see if it has any problems.  I might need to back off and do one at a time since for this project I'm using a hosted shared server.

Comment: @user1314159 SQL Server handles XML as `NVARCHAR` (*2-byte-unicode*) internally. You can send a unicode string directly into XML, or take it as `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and cast it to XML. You might even *marshal* a unicode string as BLOB and read it into `VARBINARY(MAX)`, which can be casted to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and then to XML.